# XPath Query to Retrieve Element Value and Name

Tags: google-sheets, importxml, xpath

Using the `IMPORTXML` function in Google Sheets, I'm trying to get the 'properties' element values from [this link](https://home.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/pages/xml?data=daily_treasury_yield_curve&field_tdr_date_value_month=202210) to appear with their element names as column headers.

Using the below XPath query outside Google Sheets, I'm able to get the data to display the element names and their values in rows separated by a space.  In Google Sheets, I get an error (`Imported Xml content can not be parsed.`).

```
//*[local-name() = 'properties']/*[not(*)]/concat(local-name(), ' ', .)
```

I have a sample spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GIUArC6THRn6NMlOFMLDjHi3qcQaSbckNYGGk2kUTgg/edit?usp=sharing) with the desired output.  Cell B12 contains the `IMPORTXML` formula that refers to the XPath in cell B4 (labeled as XPATH Query 2). Cell B3 ("XPATH Query 1") contains the query that seems to work outside of Google Sheets.

The below image displays the current output of cell B12 outlined in red and the desired output beginning in cell D11.

[image]

Comment: No repro. I just made a copy of your spreadsheet; the formula in B12 using IMPORTXML returns the referred error; in my copy, it returned values instead of an error. The formula uses a different xPath. Anyway, while a link to the spreadsheet is helpful, questions should be self-contained, this means that the relevant parts of the spreadsheet should be described in the question as well as the formulas and function parameters should be included in the question.

Comment: @Rubén Thanks for the feedback.  The formula in cell B12, referring to the query in cell B4, results in just the element values without the element names as displayed in the table starting in cell D11.  Changing the formula in B12 to refer to the query in cell B3 results in a parsing error in Google Sheets but the query seems to work elsewhere.  Help is appreciated.

Comment: I just opened my copy; this time, the formula in B12 returns an error, but the formula in B12 of the spreadsheet linked in the question works. This inconsistency makes the question non-suitable for this site as troubleshooting-like questions are off-topic.

Comment: One option is to eliminate the inconsistencies, in this case, the formula in B4. If this is just added to display the expected result, let's remove the formulas by doing a copy-paste as value only, and focus on xPath of B3.

Comment: By the way, when text xPath in external tools, be sure that this tool uses xPath 1.0

Comment: I don't think that there have been any formula changes made to the linked spreadsheet since the question was posted.  The problem is that the results from the formula in B12 produce only the values and not the element names and values.  The table beginning in cell D11 is the desired output, per the question.  I hope all this is clear.  Please let me know if any other questions or clarifications needed.

Comment: @BlindSpots Thanks, though this doesn't resolve the XPath query (which problem may appear with other XML calls where the element name is needed to display), this may be as close as I can get immediately.  If you set this as an answer I'll accept it.  Yes, from my experience using Google Sheets `IMPORTXML` is that it some times fails to resolve or even times out.  I don't know any reason why.

Comment: @BlindSpots You seem to know the API well.  Do you know why it some times fails to resolve with Google Sheets `IMPORTXML` function and needs to refresh the whole spreadsheet or toggle other XML calls (I haven't had this experience with the Excel equivalent)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Alternatives

Here are alternative approaches to get the data in your preferred layout:

1. [IMPORTDATA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335?hl=en)
   **`=IMPORTDATA(url, delimiter)`**
   Imports from a URL in CSV or TSV format.

   ```
   =LET(url, "https://home.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/daily-treasury-rates.csv/2022/all?type=daily_treasury_yield_curve&field_tdr_date_value=2022&page&_format=csv",
        IMPORTDATA(url, ","))
   ```
2. [IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en)
   **`=IMPORTHTML(url, query, index)`**
   Imports from a table or list within an HTML page.

   ```
   =LET(url, "https://home.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/TextView?type=daily_treasury_yield_curve&field_tdr_date_value=2022",
        table, IMPORTHTML(url, "table"),
        CHOOSECOLS(table, 1, SEQUENCE(1,13,11)))
   ```

   - [CHOOSECOLS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914?hl=en) is used to remove 9 columns from the array that were hidden columns in the source table and  are not required.
   - Column 1 (NEW_DATE) is manually entered;
   - The remain columns are specified by generating a 13 number  [SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en) from 11 to 23

### Intermittent Connection Issues

I also encountered intermittent periods during testing where the URL would stop resolving.

This affected [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en) and [IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en)  but I didn't witness it with [IMPORTDATA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335?hl=en). This may highlight a difference or I may simply have been lucky with [IMPORTDATA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335?hl=en) and it would have behaved similarly eventually.

Modifying the URL to point to a different year then changing it back seemed to resolve the issue when it showed up.

Answer (score 2):

Things to have in mind about using xPath on IMPORTXML

1. It supports xPath 1.0. An old version of the IMPORTXML help article mentioned the supported version; the current version points to a third-party tutorial about xPath hosted on https://www.w3schools.com/ that used to be unreliable. I don't know if they have improved or how Google has decided to point to that site. All of the xPath testers I found searching the Web support xPath 2.0.
2. Some time ago, I read that IMPORTXML can't return xPath function results because the above doesn't support xPath 2.0. I don't have a source to support this, but I haven't found examples that prove the contrary either.

Considering the above, and due to the difficulty of controlling the recalculation of spreadsheet formulas in Google Sheets, I lean to use Google Apps Script, the [Url Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch) and the [XML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service).

One option might be to create a custom function. This might work similarly to IMPORTXML but might include a custom retry algorithm while the execution time does not exceed 30 seconds. If a longer execution time is required, the function could be triggered by an installable trigger, a custom menu, and other options.

Comment: Yes, the documentation for Google Sheets doesn't make clear which XPath version is used though it seems v1.0.  I understand the `concat` expression I used is v2.0.  From asking around, v1.0 doesn't seem to support returning the element names either. so a custom function may be the only alternative at the moment when the data are only in XML.

Comment: @Catalyx I think that the problem is that IMPORTXML can't be included in the output of functions like `concat`, but it could be used for filtering. Considering this, it might be not precise to say that IMPORTXML doesn't support `concat`, it might be more precise to say that it doesn't fully support xPath 2.0. Anyway, the point is that IMPORTXML can't use all the XPath expressions.